# JSON.parse cannot parse a .json file

Tags: json, node.js

I have the following code:

```
router.get('/:pageName', function (req, res, next) {
  var pageName = req.params.pageName;
  var obj;
  fs.readFile('./data/' + pageName + '.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj.title);
    //render page with the data

  });
});
```

I have a file called `about.json` in `./data`.

```
        {
          "type":  "plain-text",
          "title": "About",
          "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sapien eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis."
        }
```

When I visit the page in my browser, nothing happens and this appears in my console:

```
        {
        ^

        SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
            at JSON.parse ()
            at C:\Users\username\source\repos\MyWebsite\MyWebsite\routes\index.js:34:16
            at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

I don't understand why there is this error because I checked my .json file with JSONLint

**EDIT:*

I also noticed that there were extra spaces between token and in JSON at position 0 and I copied them into a unicode character inspector: [apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BB%BF](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BB%BF) It says, it's a `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`. What's that?

Comment: I am almost certain that when you get the file, there are characters preceeding the open brace. Check that the file has absolutely nothing before that first opening brace.

Comment: @ChrisCousins I don't have any characters preceding the open brace

Comment: @MichaelMontero It still gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing it before parsing

```
var filter = new RegExp("\uFEFF");
data = data.replace(filter, '');
obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Or you can try saving json files with ‘without BOM’ option.

Comment: What is `BOM` option?

Comment: how do I save the file without BOM?

Comment: Notepad++ can save without bom